# LINQ: Sorting on many columns dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a query of IQueryable and want to apply sorting to it dynamically, sorting can be on many columns (asc or desc). I've written the following generic function:

```
    private IQueryable<T> ApplySorting<T,U>(IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, U>> predicate, SortOrder order)
    {
        if (order == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            {
                return query.OrderBy<T, U>(predicate);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            {
                return query.OrderByDescending<T, U>(predicate);
            }
        }
    }
```

SortOrder is my simple enum with 2 values: Ascending and Descending

Then I call this function in a loop, for each column that user requested sorting. However I've noticed it fails because it always sorts on the last column used, ignoring the other ones.

Then I found there's a 'ThenBy' method on IOrderedQueryable so the valid usage is:

```
var q = db.MyType.OrderBy(x=>x.Col1).ThenBy(y=>y.Col2); //etc.
```

But how can I make it generic? I tried to test if the query is IOrderedQueryable but it seems always to be true even if it's simplest var q = from x in db.MyType select x

I have no clue why it was designed like this. What's wrong with:

```
var q = db.MyType.OrderBy(x=>x.Col1).OrderBy(y=>y.Col2); //etc.
```

it's so much intuitive

Comment: I assume they don't let .OrderBy(..Col1..).OrderBy(..Col2..) fly is because they're no good way to know if the the intended end result is to order by Col1, then re-order the entire list by Col2; or Col1 then a sub ordering of Col2 (as you intended)

Comment: Query execution is deferred, when you write .OrderBy nothing happens until you iterate through the query set for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to check if the query is already ordered :

```
private IQueryable<T> ApplySorting<T,U>(IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, U>> predicate, SortOrder order)
{
    var ordered = query as IOrderedQueryable<T>;
    if (order == SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        if (ordered != null)
            return ordered.ThenBy(predicate);
        return query.OrderBy(predicate);
    }
    else
    {
        if (ordered != null)
            return ordered.ThenByDescending(predicate);
        return query.OrderByDescending(predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work. Like I said, query ALWAYS is of type IOrderedQueryable, event if it's a simplest from x in y select x;

Answer (score 1):

How about just making the first `OrderBy` static, then always `ThenBy`?

```
OrderColumn[] columnsToOrderby = getColumnsToOrderby();
IQueryable<T> data = getData();

if(!columnToOrderBy.Any()) { }
else
{
    OrderColumn firstColumn = columnsToOrderBy[0];
    IOrderedEnumerable<T> orderedData =
        firstColumn.Ascending
        ? data.OrderBy(predicate)
        : data.OrderByDescending(predicate);

    for (int i = 1; i < columnsToOrderBy.Length; i++)
    {
        OrderColumn column = columnsToOrderBy[i];
        orderedData =
            column.Ascending
            ? orderedData.ThenBy(predicate)
            : orderedData.ThenByDescending(predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this approach and works for me, with the mention that in the end I have to reassign *orderedData* to *data*: 

```data = orderedData```

I also used *.Skip(1)* extension from Linq with a *foreach* loop: 
```foreach (var sortExpr in columnsToOrderBy.Skip(1))```

Answer (score 0):

Total guess, but can you do something like this?

```
query.OrderBy(x => 1).ThenBy<T,U>(predicate)
```

Any syntax errors aside, the idea is to do an OrderBy() that doesn't affect anything, then do the real work in the .ThenBy() method call

Comment: Nice hack, and it should do the job, but still it's only a hack. It's hard to believe that linq authors did not think of such scenario. With python/django doing such things is so trivial...

Comment: While it doesn't affect the order, does it still have an impact on performance?

Answer (score 0):

I would write a wrapper around and internally use linq extension methods.

```
var resultList =   presentList
        .MyOrderBy(x => x.Something)
        .MyOrderBY(y => y.SomethingElse)
        .MyOrderByDesc(z => z.AnotherThing)

public IQueryable<T> MyOrderBy(IQueryable<T> prevList, Expression<Func<T, U>> predicate) {

       return (prevList is IOrderedQueryable<T>)
            ? query.ThenBy(predicate)
            : query.OrderBy(predicate);
}

public IQueryable<T> MyOrderByDesc(IQueryable<T> prevList, Expression<Func<T, U>> predicate) {

       return (prevList is IOrderedQueryable<T>)
            ? query.ThenByDescending(predicate)
            : query.OrderByDescending(predicate);
}
```

PS: I didn't test the code

Comment: If you test this code you will find that IQueryable<T> is always IOrderedQueryable<T>, so ThenBy function will always called and OrderBy will never be called. This is similar to how I tried to implement it before writing here and found this surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to dynamic multi-order:

```
public static class DynamicExtentions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DynamicOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, string[] orderings) where T : class
    {
        var orderedData = data.OrderBy(x => x.GetPropertyDynamic(orderings.First()));
        foreach (var nextOrder in orderings.Skip(1))
        {
            orderedData = orderedData.ThenBy(x => x.GetPropertyDynamic(nextOrder));
        }
        return orderedData;
    }

    public static object GetPropertyDynamic<Tobj>(this Tobj self, string propertyName) where Tobj : class
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tobj), "value");
        var getter = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
        var boxer = Expression.TypeAs(getter, typeof(object));
        var getPropValue = Expression.Lambda<Func<Tobj, object>>(boxer, param).Compile();            
        return getPropValue(self);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var q =(myItemsToSort.Order(["Col1","Col2"]);
```

Note: not sure any `IQueryable` provider can translate this